# .htaccess rewrite rule change url automatic

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm new to htaccess and I need some help
how do I change the url automatically from from .htaccses
if I write url like:

```
url/index.php/pages
```

url will change automatic to:

```
url/pages
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be pretty straight forward, you would have found hundreds of existing answers and examples alone here on StackOberflow...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/pages/?$ /pages [R=301]
```

This assumes that in your question, in the given path `url/index.php/pages` the "url" refers to a prefix of protocol scheme and host name, so would usually be written as `https://example.com/index.php/pages`...

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

I dare say however that you also need the corresponding internal rewrite to again be able to process such redirected requests. Adding that the example looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/pages/?$ /pages [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?pages/?$ /index.php/pages [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This get more complex if your question does not only target the single, specific path `/index.php/pages` but actually any "pages" to follow in the path after the leading `/index.php/`. For that you'd need something a bit more complex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [END]
```

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: thanks it work,
it seems I was wrong in writing the sequence before